# What's the correct way to share memory between my AssemblyScript module and my JS?

Tags: webassembly, assemblyscript

I'm following this code [here](https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/1231#issuecomment-420466909), trying to share memory between my AssemblyScript code and my JS:

```js
  let aryPtr = instance.exports.allocateF32Array(3);
  let ary = new Float32Array(instance.exports.memory.buffer, aryPtr, 3);

  ary[0] = 1.0;
  ary[1] = 2.0;
  instance.exports.addArray(aryPtr);
```

And my index.ts:

```js
export function allocateF32Array(length: i32): Float32Array {
  return new Float32Array(length);
}

export function addArray(data: Float32Array): i32 {
  data[2] = data[0] + data[1];
  return data.length;
}
```

But this results in `RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds` in `addArray`. Have I misunderstood how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use [the official loader](https://www.assemblyscript.org/loader.html) for such purposes.

On the JavaScript side: (node.js for example)

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const loader = require("@assemblyscript/loader");
const module = loader.instantiateSync(
  fs.readFileSync("optimized.wasm"),
  {}
);
var ptrArr = module.__retain(module.__allocArray(module.FLOAT32ARRAY, [1, 2, 0]));
console.log('length:', module.addArray(ptrArr));

const arr = module.__getFloat32Array(ptrArr);
console.log('result:', arr[2]);

// free array
module.__release(ptrArr);
```

On the AssemblyScript side:

```js
export const FLOAT32ARRAY = idof<Float32Array>();

export function addArray(data: Float32Array): i32 {
  data[2] = data[0] + data[1];
  return data.length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also note the existence of __getFloat32ArrayView (avoids memory copying, but can be unsafe). Also it seems that __allocArray will quietly reuse previously alloc'd memory if there's not enough available, causing hard-to-find bugs. I had to use memory.grow() in my .ts.

Comment: The official loader has been [deprecated](https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/releases/tag/v0.20.0) as of 0.20.0

Answer (score 1):

A little late but this might be useful for people ending up here.

In my opinion AssemblyScript is a fantastic language to easily adopt WASM ability into your JS/TS code. The recent release 0.25.1 comes with bindings ready on many types. Yet still you can easily implement the bindings yourself.

Remember that you can only interchange `i32`, `i64`, `f32` and `f64` data directly inbetween your host and WASM module. Besides you can access the WASM memory from JS/TS (host) side.

Let us investigate the initial part of the code

```
let aryPtr = instance.exports.allocateF32Array(3);
let ary = new Float32Array(instance.exports.memory.buffer, aryPtr, 3);

ary[0] = 1.0;
ary[1] = 2.0;
instance.exports.addArray(aryPtr);
```

- `allocateF32Array(n)` is an exported function from WASM. When you invoke it with an integer argument `n` it creates a `Float32Array` of length `n` at WASM side and passes it's pointer  back to host side. The pointer is it's location in the module memory and gets assigned to `aryPtr`.
- Then on the second line it creates a seperate `Float32Array` just to use as a view to access the WASM memory. So it passes the buffer to use, offset (pointer), and length) to the `Float32Array` constructor. Now you can access the WASM memory's related part through `ary`. Any modification you do on `ary` will actually happen on the WASM side `Float32Array`.
- Make some assignments to index 0 and 1.
- Call another exported function `addArray(ptr)` with the pointer of it.

Now you should implement the `allocateF32Array` and `addArray`) functions to export.

- Creating a `TypedArray` is somewhat [very similar to normal JS](https://www.assemblyscript.org/stdlib/typedarray.html#constructor) in AssemblyScript (AS).

`allocateF32Array(n)`:

```
export function allocateF32Array(length: i32): i32 {
  const arr : Float32Array = new Float32Array(length);
  return changetype<i32>(arr); // return the pointer
}
```

- And the other function can be implemented as follows

`addArray(ptr)`:

```
export function addArray(ptr: usize): f32 {
  const arr : Float32Array = changetype<Float32Array>(ptr); // obtain Float32Array from the pointer
  return arr[0] + arr[1];
}
```

Finally, this is in fact the raw method and you don't really need to get this low. Nowadays the bindings are readily implemented in the `.build/release.js` file from where you import the exported function just like ESM imports.